# I want to display few images randomly in java (android)

Tags: java, android, oop

```
package com.example.paul_2.a5mai;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int first=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        start();
    }
    void start () {

//root layout
        LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);
        root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        root.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        setContentView(root);

//butonul de start
        Button StartBTN = new Button(this);
        StartBTN.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        StartBTN.setText("Click Me");
        root.addView(StartBTN);


// contine toate cele 5 layouturi
        final LinearLayout linearContainer=new LinearLayout(this);
        linearContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        root.addView(linearContainer);

//LINIA 1
        final LinearLayout firstRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        firstRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        firstRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        linearContainer.addView(firstRow);

        //dimensiunea imaginii
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(260,260);
        //params1.leftMargin =10;
        //params1.topMargin = 10;
       final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
       /* final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);

        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(3) + 1; // n = the number of images, that start at idx 1
        String imgName = "img" + rndInt;
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        imgView.setImageResource(id);
        firstRow.addView(imgView, params1);*/


        /*final ImageView imgView2 = new ImageView(this);

        Random rand2 = new Random();
        int rndInt2 = rand2.nextInt(3) + 1;
        String imgName2 = "img" + rndInt2;
        int id2 = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName2, "drawable", getPackageName());
        imgView2.setImageResource(id2);
        firstRow.addView(imgView2, params1);


        final ImageView imgView3 = new ImageView(this);

        Random rand3 = new Random();
        int rndInt3 = rand3.nextInt(3) + 1;
        String imgName3 = "img" + rndInt3;
        int id3 = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName3, "drawable", getPackageName());
        imgView3.setImageResource(id3);
        firstRow.addView(imgView3, params1);*/


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        final LinearLayout secondRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        secondRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        secondRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        linearContainer.addView(secondRow);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        final LinearLayout thirdRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        thirdRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        thirdRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        linearContainer.addView(thirdRow);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        final LinearLayout fourthRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        fourthRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        fourthRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        linearContainer.addView(fourthRow);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        final LinearLayout fivethRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        fivethRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        fivethRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        linearContainer.addView(fivethRow);

        StartBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                first=1;


                //ImageView imgView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

                Random rand = new Random();
                int rndInt = rand.nextInt(3) + 1; // n = the number of images, that start at idx 1
                String imgName = "img" + rndInt;
                int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                imgView.setImageResource(id);
                firstRow.addView(imgView, params1);

                ImageView imgView2 = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

                Random rand2 = new Random();
                int rndInt2 = rand2.nextInt(3) + 1;
                String imgName2 = "img" + rndInt2;
                int id2 = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName2, "drawable", getPackageName());
                imgView2.setImageResource(id2);
                firstRow.addView(imgView2, params1);


                ImageView imgView3 = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

                Random rand3 = new Random();
                int rndInt3 = rand3.nextInt(3) + 1;
                String imgName3 = "img" + rndInt3;
                int id3 = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName3, "drawable", getPackageName());
                imgView3.setImageResource(id3);
                firstRow.addView(imgView3, params1);



                final Animation animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide);
                firstRow.startAnimation(animSlide);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to generate this images randomly by clicking StartBTN. The code works but the problem is that the images generated the first time I click on the button remains and next time I click the button they dont change. I need to generate everytime I click the botton. What can I do? Where I should declare the objects? How else I can do this? Thank you in advance!

> logcat after moveing the declaration of the objects outsite the onClick event:
>   05-17 13:49:26.236 8757-8757/com.example.paul_2.a5mai E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: com.example.paul_2.a5mai, PID: 8757
>                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4417)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4258)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4230)
>       at com.example.paul_2.a5mai.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:127)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: I forgot de mention that I have 3 images copied into "drawable" folder.

Comment: So before I present a coded solution just for confirmation, your code generates imageViews with images in them when you click the button(is this working for you perfectly?) and you want the to distribute 3 images randomly among 3 imageViews everytime you click the button. Is that correct?

Comment: The first time when I click the button it generates 3 images randomly and make an animation with them. The second time the animation starts again but the problem is that are the same images from the first time. The random function doesn't work again...

Comment: How can I solve the next error: 
                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont add ImageViews every time.  The problem is , first time added image is not removed. So it still shows.

Do the following only once outside of your button click.

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
ImageView imgView2 = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
ImageView imgView3 = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
```

Now inside your click event, get the image views and change the resources like this

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bike);
```

Don't add views again and again. These statements should be done only once in your code

```
thirdRow.addView(imgView3, params1);
```

Comment: and the addView where I should write?

Comment: and how can I solve the next error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. ?

Answer (score 0):

You think that you get same number every time but you don't. You are adding everything to the first row but you see only those images which are showed at the first time at the top of first row. Add ImageView views to second and third row at the end of creating ever ImageView in button listener and you'll generate new rows with random images:

```
        StartBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

            Random rand = new Random();
            int rndInt = rand.nextInt(3) + 1; // n = the number of images, that start at idx 1
            String imgName = "img" + rndInt;
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
            imgView.setImageResource(id);
            firstRow.addView(imgView, params1);

            ImageView imgView2 = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

            Random rand2 = new Random();
            int rndInt2 = rand2.nextInt(3) + 1;
            String imgName2 = "img" + rndInt2;
            int id2 = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName2, "drawable", getPackageName());
            imgView2.setImageResource(id2);
            secondRow.addView(imgView2, params1);


            ImageView imgView3 = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

            Random rand3 = new Random();
            int rndInt3 = rand3.nextInt(3) + 1;
            String imgName3 = "img" + rndInt3;
            int id3 = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName3, "drawable", getPackageName());
            imgView3.setImageResource(id3);
            thirdRow.addView(imgView3, params1);



            final Animation animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide);
            firstRow.startAnimation(animSlide);
            secondRow.startAnimation(animSlide);
            thirdRow.startAnimation(animSlide);

        }
    });
```

**EDIT remove views before adding new one**

i.e.:

```
 firstRow.removeAllViews();
 firstRow.addView(imgView, params1);
```

or

```
 firstRow.removeView(v);
 firstRow.addView(imgView, params1);
```

or

```
 firstRow.removeAllViewsInLayout();
 firstRow.addView(imgView, params1);
```

Comment: How can I solve the next error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. ?

Comment: Post the entire log whereyou can see clearly which view is problematic.

Comment: I edited the post with adding the logs. Can you please look at this? I really need help.

Comment: What does it mean "moveing the declaration of the objects outsite the onClick event:" ?  I tested my answer which i posted and i don't get any exception. If you try my answer, which changes only three lines, there is no exception and you egt your rows

Comment: I edited my entire code, look now at this and you will see the exception I get. What I can do now? P.S. I dont want to display the images in different rows, like you posted ( I need the rest of the rows for something else later).

Comment: You should read what logs say to you. It says that on Line 127 you should remove view before adding new one. Check my edit in the answer.

Comment: Yeah. The problem was I should't addView everytime I click the button. I had to call addView just ONE time and now works.I didn't has to use removeView. Thank's for helping!